# Merging threads in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, merge, threading

Is it possible to merge threads in Thunderbird?

I recently got into a discussion where one person was consistently not using "Reply", but starting new threads. I'd like to merge all such emails into one thread.

I know that [at least `mutt` has this feature](http://www.mail-archive.com/mutt-users@mutt.org/msg32508.html).

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This feature request is in the Thunderbird bug report system since April 2000 https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=36024

But still not yet implemented :-(