# Merging threads in IMAP

Tags: email, merge, threads

A follow-up to [Merging threads in Thunderbird](https://superuser.com/questions/259172/merging-threads-in-thunderbird). I realized that when using IMAP I can try merging threads in another application... So, which modern email applications can merge threads in IMAP accounts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mutt supports imap. So from your previous thread, as mutt supports merging in general, did you check if it supports merging specifically for imap ?

Comment: +1 Yes, technically it does. But I'd like to see something with more graphical UI.