# How do I achieve proper threading on Thunderbird?

Tags: email, thunderbird

I'm running Thunderbird 24 on Ubuntu 12.04 64 bits. I have installed the [Conversations](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/gmail-conversation-view/) extension, in order to group and visualize conversations based on threads, in a similar way to what gmail does.

It works fine, but it seems to depend on Thunderbird's internal native thread grouping mechanism, that is itself a bit flawed. In  the example below, this thread include **four** different subjects.

[image]

I know many will say the threads are grouped based on an internal flag and if a contact of mine lazily uses a previous message, click reply to obtain the address list of an existing message and use it as a basis to compose a new message, with a different subject, then the new message will be automatically threaded as a child of the original message.

The problem is:

1. I can't educate ALL my contacts. Simply impossible;
2. Thunderbird is grouping messages with ***different*** subject lines
3. I have received automatic messages from external services, (meaning it's impossible they had hit "reply" on a previous conversation) and even then it gets grouped on a wrong thread.

Is there a way for me to improve the way Thunderbird will group threads? Or alternativaly a way that I can manually exclude and include messages from threads (that doesn't involve having to manually edit headers)?

Comment: related: https://github.com/protz/GMail-Conversation-View/wiki/What-is-threading and https://wiki.mozilla.org/Thunderbird:Help_Documentation:Hidden_Preferences and http://kb.mozillazine.org/Stop_threading_by_subject and https://wiki.mozilla.org/MailNews:Message_Threading

Comment: If you want it group by subject then turn off conversation mode and just sort by the subject column.  I think what your finding is actually the point of conversation view... to group related messages, regardless of title.  So if someone replies to one of your messages in a conversation, then of course it's part of that same "conversation". So I think you're stuck.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 whats is conversation mode and how to turn off? How to make like in Gmail? https://superuser.com/questions/1530240/how-to-get-thunderbird-grouping-while-threding-to-look-like-gmail-exactly

Comment: After 10 years, the problem is still here.

Answer (score 12):

It seems to happen frequently when I move threaded emails from a folder to another.

Solved by a simple two-step operation :

1. Compact the folder this thread is in (right-click then `compact`).
2. Repair this folder (right-click then `properties`).

You should try to repair first, but for some reason it may fail. Then just compact & repair.

Comment: @ThatBrazilianGuy Thanks for the rewrite, it's more clear now. Did you find a solution for your problem (two years ago, indeed), if yes what is it ?

Comment: Yeah, a great feature of the Stack Exchange site is they are technically a "wiki". Sometimes people are a little OCD in their edits, sorry if it's the case ;P

Comment: About my problem, I had simply given up organizing conversations in threads / folders and simply using "inbox" and "archived". I will try your suggested solution (on a huge folder, it might take a while...) and accept the answer if it works!

Comment: Did you try this ? (and does it work ?)

Comment: Compacting is quick, but repairing takes ages on large folders.. is their any better fix to this problem?

Comment: @kapad Not really... First, make a copy of your TB profile, it could save your (digital) life. You then have to wait for the repair to finish, it may indeed take centuries to complete. I saw cases where four successive repair processes were necessary to recover the folder. Good luck !